# Strange output when trying to find prime numbers Python

Tags: python, boolean, primes

Ok, so I admittedly am kind of a noob, and I've been going through a course on udemy for programming.  The problem is asking to write a function that finds all the prime numbers up to the number given.  So I started writing the following code to extract the numbers that are not even, as well as the numbers not evenly divisible by 3 just to start:

```
def count_primes(num):
    num_list5 = []
    for i in range(num + 1):
        print(i)
        if i % 2 != 0 or i % 3 != 0:
            num_list5.append(i)
    
    return num_list5
```

When I call the function with a number of 100 like:
`count_primes(100)`
In the output, I get the `num_list5` showing all the numbers in the range except for 6 and multiples of 6:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14 ...]`

Its like the if statement is doing an AND operation here... because 6 would be divisible by 2 AND 3.  Is this a bug or something? Or am I not understanding and/or operations correctly?

What's weird is that it was working at one point and after making a change and reverting it, it started doing this...

I'm using VSCode and Jupyter notebooks and tried both Python 3.8.5 64-bit and 3.9.4 64-bit on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is your goal to have this output the number of primes less than or equal to num?

Comment: Your code is doing as it should. You are adding all numbers that are NOT divisible by 2 & 3 at the same time, which is 6 (2*3) and all multiples of 6. It should be AND and not or.  6%2 != 0 is false and 6%3 != 0 is also false, which is why they are not appended to the list.

Comment: Well, it is sort of doing an AND.  Remember that (NOT A OR NOT B) is equal to NOT(A AND B).  You omit a number if is both divisible by 2 AND divisible by 3.

Answer (score 8):

`i % 2 != 0 or i % 3 != 0` is equal to  `not (i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0)` (De Morgan's laws)

It should be `i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0`

Comment: Yeah, I should've seen this as I've just recently started studying discrete math and propositional math, but still seeing it represented here is a weird concept, since I thought that Python will look at the first comparison and if its true will enter the conditional statement and if false goes to the second comparison to see if its True/False

Comment: @ArturoCastillin You are rigth about the order of operation. After first one is true it doesn't check the second one but when first one is true that means allow to pass every odd number(i % 2 != 0) , if it is false then check every even number that is not divisible by 3. So every even number not divisible by 3 + all odd numbers = all numbers except multiple of 6

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to generate all primes less than `num`, you should loop over all numbers `j` less than `i` and check if `i%j` is zero rather than just 2 and 3.

```py
def count_primes(num):
    num_list5 = []
    for i in range(2, num + 1): # start at 2 because 1 and zero are not primes
        print(i)
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i%j == 0:
                break
        else:
            num_list5.append(i)
    
    return num_list5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100
    print(count_primes(n))
```

Note that using Sieve of Eratosthenes method, this can be done more efficiently:

```py
import math

def count_primes_sieve(num):
    num_list5 = [False, False] + [True]*(num - 1)
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):
        if num_list5[i]:
            j = i * i
            while j < len(num_list5):
                num_list5[j] = False
                j += i
    return [i for i, p in enumerate(num_list5) if p]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100
    print(count_primes_sieve(n))
```

Comment: Remember that you only have to search up to `sqrt(i)`.  You don't need to go all the way to `i`.

Comment: @TimRoberts ... I forget this every time.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

We know some facts about prime numbers which you can use in your program.  Negative numbers, 0 and 1 are not prime.  2 is the only even prime.  A prime number only has itself and 1 as factors.  From multiplication we know that if a x b = c then one of a, b is <= sqrt(c).  That last fact helps us cut down the number of trial divisors we have to test.  We can test for a prime by looking for a number that divides the target but is not the target itself or 1.  If we find such a number then the target is not prime.

Here is some pseudocode to help:

```
function isPrime(num)
  // 1, 0, negatives not prime.
  if (num < 2)
    return false
  end if
  
  // 2 is the only even prime.
  if (num MOD 2 = 0)
    return (num = 2)
  end if

  // Try odd factors up to square root.
  limit <- 1 + sqrt(num)
  for (test <- 3; test < limit; test <- test + 2)
    if (num MOD test = 0)
      // Not prime, we have found a factor. 
      return false
    end if
  end for

  // If we get this far then num is prime.
  return true

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out the propositional math and de Morgan's Law as someone pointed out, I was able to come up with a pretty simple solution using or and mod operators and only goes through a the sequence once:

```
def count_primes(num):

    num_list5 = []

    for i in range(2, num + 1):
        if i == 2 or i == 3 or i == 5 or i == 7:
            num_list5.append(i)
        if not (i % 2 == 0 or i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 or i % 7 == 0):
            num_list5.append(i)
    
    return num_list5

print(count_primes(100))
```